# Better way to do a str_replace on csv value

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to look for a degree character in uploaded csv's before they are hitting my output method. As I'm writing how I would normally do this I feel like my solution will involve way more steps than it should. So, **I'm asking is there a better way to look for a `°` symbol in a csv file and replace it with `&#176;`. Here's what the approach I'm currently taking:

```
$file       = get_attached_file( $csv_file ); //set file_path
$file_array = array(); //declare an array so it gets key and values approriately
$array_key  = 'angle'; //define where the degree symbol is to be added
$file_array = str_getcsv(file_get_contents($file));
if( array_key_exists($array_key, $file_array) ) {
    foreach ($file_array as $key => $value) {
        $degree  = '°';
        $replace = '&#176';
        $value = str_replace($degree, $replace, $value);
    }
}
```

My problem is, wouldn't I then have to loop through each value in the array, put it back in a csv which would then require me to define what columns need to be outputted when some files won't have the `angle` column I'm trying to replace in the first place.
Also, will php be able to find and decode the `°` symbol.

Comment: do you only want to remove "°" symbol, or any special char ? If you don't care, you may use html_entities to encode all your string once for all...

Comment: just the degree symbol

Comment: is there any other special char in your string ?

Comment: no that is the only special character but my output funtion is looking for a csv not an array.

Comment: If there are no other special chars, then you would use [html_entities()](php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), which should (in your case) only replace the "°". The reverse action is html_entity_decode()...

Comment: wouldn't I be able to append the existing file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If replacing the degree symbol is the only thing which concerns you then this is going to be more efficient from a micro-optimization standpoint because you can skip calling the `foreach(){}` loop and only need to call `str_replace()` one time:

```
$file_array = str_getcsv(str_replace('°', '&#176;', file_get_contents($file)));
```

---

Update per the comments:

```
// Read the CSV file into a PHP variable as a string
// Replace all ° with &#176;
// Overwrite the original file with the new string
file_put_contents($file, str_replace('°', '&#176;', file_get_contents($file)));
```

Comment: @MonkeyZesus this doesn't full get me there. I would still need to put the results back into (*at the bottom of my question*). If possible, I would like to keep the same csv file upload and append those characters if necessary. Unless, I'm mistaken that would return an array and my function to output would be looking for a csv

Comment: @AustinMauldin I don't quite understand all of your requirements. Are you looking to fix the file upon being uploaded and saved to your server so that you only have to replace the degree symbol one time, ever? Or are you looking to replace the degree symbol only when the user wishes to look at/download the data? Also, what do you mean by "append"? According to your question your are **replacing** a character with it's entity equivalent.

Comment: The file goes to a function another developer made that takes a csv file as a parameter. I was hoping there was a way to replace the characters in a csv file without having to overwrite it by iterating over each row.

Comment: could I just put the contents after that?